# Laravel Eloquent - Get Eloquent Relationship Model Data From nested Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, mode

I have 3 models like this-

**User**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $fillable =   [
                                'profile_picture',
                                'first_name',
                                'last_name',
                                'email',
                                'cell_no',
                                'website',
                                'date_of_birth',
                                'social_security_number_p1',
                                'social_security_number_p2',
                                'social_security_number_p3',
                                'address',
                                'location_latitude',
                                'location_longitude',
                                'password',
                                'user_type',
                                'is_enabled'
                            ];

    protected $hidden = [
                            'password',
                            'remember_token',
                            'id',
                            'user_type',
                            'is_enabled',
                            'created_at',
                            'updated_at'
                        ];

    public function advertisement()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Advertisement', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Advertisement**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

class Advertisement extends Model
{
    protected $fillable     =   [
                                    'user_id',
                                    'category_id',
                                    'sub_category_id',
                                    'title',
                                    'price',
                                    'description',
                                    'address',
                                    'location_lat',
                                    'location_lon',
                                    'is_active',
                                    'deleted_at'
                                ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function Offer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Offer', 'add_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Offer**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =   [
                                'add_id',
                                'user_id',
                                'price',
                                'message'
                            ];

    public function User()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','user_id','id');
    }

    public function Advertisement()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\advertisement','add_id','id');
    }
}
```

I want to get advertisements with offer and offers with offer sender (user).

So, I am doing something like this-

```
return Advertisement::with('AdvertisementImages')
    ->with('Offer')
    ->with('User')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

And getting this-

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 16,
        "title": "123asd",
        "price": 123,
        "description": "asd asd asd ",
        "address": "Dhaka University Campus, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
        "location_lat": 23.73,
        "location_lon": 90.39,
        "total_views": "110",
        "avg_rating": "4.0000",
        "is_reviewed": 0,
        "is_offer_sent": 1,
        "advertisement_images": [
            {
                "image_name": "16-68261.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image_name": "16-34746.JPG"
            },
            {
                "image_name": "16-79570.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "offer": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 9,
                "price": 123,
                "message": "asd ad asdasd ",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:22:43",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-11 02:22:43"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 15,
                "price": 43,
                "message": "as dfasd ",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:24:04",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-11 02:24:04"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 16,
                "price": 23,
                "message": "hgf",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:25:31",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-12 01:37:42"
            }
        ],
        "user": {
            "profile_picture": "",
            "first_name": "Ne",
            "last_name": "Ajgor",
            "cell_no": null,
            "email": "ajgor@me.com",
            "website": "",
            "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00",
            "social_security_number_p1": "",
            "social_security_number_p2": "",
            "social_security_number_p3": "",
            "address": "",
            "location_latitude": 0,
            "location_longitude": 0
        }
    }
]
```

So, it is wrong. I am getting user from **Advertisement**.

But I like to have user from **Offer**.

So, I need to have something like this-

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 16,
        "title": "123asd",
        "price": 123,
        "description": "asd asd asd ",
        "address": "Dhaka University Campus, Dhaka, Dhaka Division, Bangladesh",
        "location_lat": 23.73,
        "location_lon": 90.39,
        "total_views": "110",
        "avg_rating": "4.0000",
        "is_reviewed": 0,
        "is_offer_sent": 1,
        "advertisement_images": [
            {
                "image_name": "16-68261.jpg"
            },
            {
                "image_name": "16-34746.JPG"
            },
            {
                "image_name": "16-79570.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "offer": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 9,
                "price": 123,
                "message": "asd ad asdasd ",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:22:43",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-11 02:22:43",
                "user": {
                    "profile_picture": "",
                    "first_name": "Me",
                    "last_name": "Ajgor",
                    "cell_no": null,
                    "email": "ajgor@me.com",
                    "website": "",
                    "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00",
                    "social_security_number_p1": "",
                    "social_security_number_p2": "",
                    "social_security_number_p3": "",
                    "address": "",
                    "location_latitude": 0,
                    "location_longitude": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 15,
                "price": 43,
                "message": "as dfasd ",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:24:04",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-11 02:24:04",
                "user": {
                    "profile_picture": "",
                    "first_name": "Ne",
                    "last_name": "Ajgor",
                    "cell_no": null,
                    "email": "ajgor@me.com",
                    "website": "",
                    "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00",
                    "social_security_number_p1": "",
                    "social_security_number_p2": "",
                    "social_security_number_p3": "",
                    "address": "",
                    "location_latitude": 0,
                    "location_longitude": 0
                }
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "add_id": 1,
                "user_id": 16,
                "price": 23,
                "message": "hgf",
                "created_at": "2016-08-11 02:25:31",
                "updated_at": "2016-08-12 01:37:42",
                "user": {
                    "profile_picture": "",
                    "first_name": "Je",
                    "last_name": "Ajgor",
                    "cell_no": null,
                    "email": "ajgor@me.com",
                    "website": "",
                    "date_of_birth": "0000-00-00",
                    "social_security_number_p1": "",
                    "social_security_number_p2": "",
                    "social_security_number_p3": "",
                    "address": "",
                    "location_latitude": 0,
                    "location_longitude": 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Can anyone please help me, what I need to call?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Have you tried using the "dot" syntax? See the ["Nested Eager Loading"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) section.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it like this-

```
Advertisement::with('AdvertisementImages')
    ->with('Offer','Offer.User')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->has('Offer')
    ->get();
```